# Newman-Penrose formalism's identity between the metric's tensor and the spin-space symplectic metric

Tags: metric-tensor, spinors

In the appendix A1 of R. Penrose's book "Cycles of time" (p.222) several identifications are made between tensors and 2-index spinors. I am interested in particular in the relationship between the metric tensor and the symplectic spin space metric $\epsilon_{AB}$ where $A$ and $B$ are spin indices. It is written in abstract index notation. The unprimed indices indicate indices of a "simple/standard" spinor whereas the primed ones indicate indices of a complex conjugated (here 2-index) spinor. But as the symplectic spin space metric $\epsilon$ is real no bar was put on the second  $\epsilon$:

$$g_{ab} = \epsilon_{AB}\epsilon_{A'B'}$$

Later I found a corresponding identification also in the book of R.Wald on GR ($g_{AB A'B'}$ symbolizing the spinor pendant of the metric tensor $g_{ab}$).

$$g_{AA'BB'} = \epsilon_{AB}\epsilon_{A'B'}   \tag{13.1.15} $$

Further on in the chapter 13 of Wald's book I found a kind of justification of this identification($\eta_{ab}$ symbolizing the flat Minkowski space metric):

$$\eta_{ab}=\sigma_{a}^{CC'}\sigma_b^{DD'} g_{CC'DD'}  \tag{13.1.43}$$

A similar formula, (8.74), can also be found in the book of Sexl & Urbantke "Relativity, Groups and Particles" (Ger. edition). The latter source is only about SR, so Minkowski metric. The $\sigma_{a}^{CC'}$ are the 4-dimensional Pauli-matrices $(1,\mathbf{\sigma_a})$ where $\mathbf{\sigma}_a$ symbolize the components of the 3 Pauli-matrices.

What is meant by the metric here ? Is the identification given only valid for Minkowski space or would it be also valid in curved space-time ? If yes how can it be since spinors can only live in (at least local) Minkowski space? On the other hand  Newman-Penrose formalism is in particular used in curved space-time so I can hardly imagine that this identification is only thought for Minkowski space. So what is the solution ?